# Python 64bit, Ctypes ReadProcessMemory ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY, Windows 7 64bit

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, readprocessmemory

My examples are base on the book "Gray Hat Python" (http://expect-us.net/files/Gray%20Hat%20Python%20=rwt911=.pdf)

There is a small example application printf_loop:

```
from ctypes import *
import time

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
counter = 0

while True:
    msvcrt.printf("Loop iteration %d!\n" % counter)
    time.sleep(2)
    counter += 1
```

Now I am trying to get the address of printf used in this application. But my ReadProcessMemory call is always returning ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY.

```
def read_process_memory(self, address, length):
    data = ""
    read_buff = create_string_buffer(length)
    count = c_ulong(0)
    if not kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(self.h_process, address, read_buff, length, byref(count)):
        print "[*] Error Code: 0x%08x" % kernel32.GetLastError()
        print read_buff.raw
        return False
    else:
        data += read_buff.raw
        return data
```

I am getting the address throughout the following function, where dll='msvcrt.dll' and function='printf':

```
 def func_resolve(self, dll, function):
    handle = c_void_p()
    kernel32.GetModuleHandleExA(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, dll, byref(handle))
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, function)
    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)

    return address
```

Do you have any suggestions why I am not able to read the memory?

Comment: At least you need to [specify the required argument and return types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) for `msvcrt.printf`, `kernel32.ReadProcessMemory`, etc. Otherwise the C `int` type is assumed.

Comment: Well after doing that for all ctype functions i was using I finally found my error. In the function read_process_memory the size of count needs to be c_ulonglong in order to work with 64bit. Thanks a lot cgohlke!